# X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory in Windows 8

Tags: c, netbeans

The compiler of Netbeans reads:

> gcc -c -g -Wall  -I/usr/openwin/include graphics.c
>   graphics.c:13:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
>    #include < X11/Xlib.h>
>   compilation terminated.
>   make.exe": *** [graphics.o] Error 1"

Although there are questions asked about X11/Xlib.h on the site I found none which applies for Windows (as the existing solutions all just seem to work on Mac os). I am really new to programming, so any enlightenment is welcomed!

Comment: Wait: `openwin` ? how old is the source you're trying to build? (and as BadZen says, it's not going to work on windows without some extra software)

Comment: Not with gcc (with MSVC) but on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22283867/2994596. Rational for error is still relevant (though the solution for using those old sources may not be)

Comment: Well I think the source is pretty old...it's actually one of my introductory projects on how to debug a large program.

Comment: Must have been on a Sun workstation.

Answer (score 3):

X Servers are generally found only on Unix-like operating systems.   Graphical programming for Windows generally uses a completely different interface.

That said, there /are/ X servers for windows - you'll need to install one, and it's associated SDK, to do any compiling for X, however.

Comment: Yes I use Xming on Windows here. Works great.

Comment: Consider using the excellent 'cygwin' library / pseudo-platform for compiling this.   I guarantee you there's going to be a lot more that won't compile, even with the X system.   Even getting it going /w cygwin may proof a task.

www.cygwin.com

What exactly are you trying to compile, by the way?

Comment: To be honest I am only required to debug a small session of the large piece of code, and I am not required to know anything about the other parts of the code, which includes where the "#include <X11/Xlib.h>" is. But it's always interesting to learn things further than what I'm currently taught.

Comment: In that case, assuming you have to debug a part that requires anything with openwin - I would go find yourself an old solaris pizza box /w openwin to work on. =)

Otherwise, I'd write a small test harness which runs just the parts of the code you need to debug, on your modern OS.

Comment: Aha interesting! I'll go read up materials on solaris..but based on current school work, I will need to make that harness happen soon. Thank you for your help!